# Редирект после login в Meteor

Tags: meteor

Использую iron:router в Meteor.
Существует ли простой способ сделать редирект пользователя на /userprofile после logIn или SignUp?

Answer (score 2):

Форма логина у меня своя и стало быть в контроллере *login.js* у меня вот такой код:

```
function loginCallBack(error){
    if( ! error ){
        Router.go('main');
    } else {
        console.log("Проблема с логином");
    }
}

Template.login.events({
    'submit #signin': function(event,template){
        var name = template.find('#username').value;
        var password = template.find('#password').value;
        event.preventDefault();
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(name, password, loginCallBack);        
    },
    'click #reg': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        Router.go('register');
    }


});
```

в *loginCallBack* обработка возможных ошибок логина и перенаправление на шаблон *main*.